# Generic class with method taking a different generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry for asking what seems like such an obvious question.

I have an "adapter" generic class of type T where T is a defined interface. I want to create a method in that class which takes a different type of generic adapter.

```
public interface ICommon { }
public class TypeOne : ICommon { }
public class TypeTwo : ICommon { }

public class Adapter<T> where T : ICommon
{
    void TakeAnotherType(Adapter<S> other)
    { }
}
```

This gives me a compilation error `Cannot resolve symbol 'S'`.

I would like to be able to do;

```
    MyOne one = new Adapter<TypeOne>();
    MyTwo two = new Adapter<TypeTwo>();
    one.TakeAnotherType(two);
```

If I change the method to take `Adapter<T>` then it complains that "two" isn't of type `Adapter<TypeOne>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void TakeAnotherType<S>(Adapter<S> other) where S:ICommon
{ }
```

Because the generic type `T` of `Adapter` is constrained to `ICommon`, it is important to also constrain `S` in the same way, as this is used as the generic type for `Adapter<T>`, so it must also satisfy the `ICommon` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
void TakeAnotherType(Adapter<S> other)
```

into

```
void TakeAnotherType<S>(Adapter<S> other) where S : ICommon
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have specified that a class is generic (by naming it `Something<T>`), every method within it is implicitly generic on that type `T`. To say that a method is generic on a *different* type, you have to specify that fact in the method name, by calling it `SomeMethod<U>`. The body of this method will then have access to both types, `T` (the type that the *class* is generic on) and `U` (the class that the *method* is generic on).

Note also that the two usual conventions for type parameters are `T`, `U`, `V` etc; or `TSomething`, `TSomethingElse`, `TEvenMore`. I don't think I've ever seen `S` used...